# Counting codes from one table in multiple tables returning 0s

Tags: sql, join, count, hsqldb

I am new to SQL and databases. I'm using them to code data for an academic paper (assign relevant information tags to various sentences). I've looked around, but my newness to SQL might have me missing the right way to search out an answer.

I have several tables where I want to count all instances of codes per table in a given field. In CODES I have a series of codes that can be updated as needed. The other tables have fields which are filled in using the codes.

```
CODES
ID  GR  SR  CT
1   S
2   A
3   P
4       S
5       DO
6       IO
7           T
8           I
DATA1
ID  IGR ISR ICT
1   S   S   T
2   P   DO  T
3   S   IO  I
4   S   DO  I
DATA2
ID  IGR ISR ICT
1   A   S   T
2   A   S   T
3   P   S   T
4   P   DO  T

EXPECTED RESULTS:
CODES.GR    DATA1.IGR   DATA2.IGR
S           3           0   
A           0           2
P           1           2
```

I have tried  the following code:

```sql
SELECT "CODES"."CT",
COUNT ("IGR") AS "DATA1.IGR",
COUNT ("IGR") AS "DATA2.IGR"
FROM
"DATA1", "DATA2"
JOIN "CODES" ON "CODES"."GR" = "DATA1"."IGR"
JOIN "CODES" ON "CODES"."GR" = "DATA2"."IGR"
GROUP BY
"CODES"."GR"
```

which gives me results in the 1000s per code per table where I would expect less than 100 per code per table. I have tried different JOINs to no avail.

The codes number upwards of 15-20 per column. SUM CASE WHENs won't update whenever I add codes so those are less than ideal. The format of the output is not necessarily set in stone if there's a way to UNION the queries together. The ideal query pulls all the codes from CODES.column, counts all instances and returns 0 when not used. I want to run this single query across 11 tables.

I am using OpenOffice Base which runs the HSQL database engine.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sql
SELECT c.GR, 
       COALESCE(a.IGR1, 0) IGR1,
       COALESCE(b.IGR2, 0) IGR2
  FROM codes c LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT IGR, COUNT(*) IGR1
    FROM data1
   WHERE IGR IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY IGR
) a ON c.GR = a.IGR LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT IGR, COUNT(*) IGR2
    FROM data2
   WHERE IGR IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY IGR
) b ON c.GR = b.IGR
 WHERE c.GR IS NOT NULL
```

or

```sql
SELECT c.GR,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM data1 
         WHERE IGR = c.GR) IGR1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM data2 
         WHERE IGR = c.GR) IGR2
  FROM codes c
 WHERE c.GR IS NOT NULL
```

Output for both queries:

```
| GR | IGR1 | IGR2 |
--------------------
|  S |    3 |    0 |
|  A |    0 |    2 |
|  P |    1 |    2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19efc/22)** demo for both queries in MySql. It should also work just fine on HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do that in Oracle:

```
SELECT c.gr, d1.cnt, d2.cnt
  FROM codes c
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT igr, COUNT(*) cnt FROM data1 GROUP BY igr) d1 ON c.gr=d1.igr
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT igr, COUNT(*) cnt FROM data2 GROUP BY igr) d2 ON c.gr=d2.igr
;
```

Though that would give null=blank instead of 0. To fix that, you could do:

```
SELECT c.gr
     , CASE WHEN d1.cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d1.cnt END
     , CASE WHEN d2.cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d2.cnt END
  FROM codes c
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT igr, COUNT(*) cnt FROM data1 GROUP BY igr) d1 ON c.gr=d1.igr
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT igr, COUNT(*) cnt FROM data2 GROUP BY igr) d2 ON c.gr=d2.igr
;
```